# How to display 'cameraIris' Shutter Open effect from middle of the view to out side

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboard, catransition

Now **I need to add cameraIris' Shutter Open effect when switch from one view to another view.**

[image]

*I used for navigation transactions as follows,* using http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CATransition

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
      transition.duration = 0.8;
      transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

   //cameraIris Effect
      [transition setType:@"cameraIris"];


      transition.delegate = self;
      [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:NextView animated:YES];
```

**But now it was closes from out side to middle i need to open this effect from middle to out side / insted of close**

can any one please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate transition effect `cameraIrisHollowClose` and `cameraIrisHollowOpen` in addition to `cameraIris`, so you could have two separate animations, one for opening and one for closing, triggered whenever you need them.

Comment: I did exact this. Now I have the problem that the closed iris disappears as the animation is completed. I want to keep the shutter closed, do some view changes and open it again. I tried to copy the presentation layer and also set `shutterAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO` But I had no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: The trick, I believe, is to say `animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards`

Comment: GREAT! Thanks, @DaGaMs! This did the trick. I then did my reverse animation using `-animationDidStop:finished:` delegate method. Works great!

Comment: Due it is private API, do you any class or open source stuff that imitates this behavior so I could submit the app?

Comment: @Julian Not aware of any OS implementation. There are a fair number of apps that use the effect, so I'd be willing to try getting it through review.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I googled quite a long time for an alternative. And I thought Apple would be very fussy with private APIs. I'll try to get it to the AppStore. If I recall this conversation I'll post my experiences. Nice evening!